# Calculate Best Content from Rating and Downloads

Tags: estimation, ranking

I'm currently storing the following things in my Database about user submitted content:

- Downloads: The total Download count of the Content
- Likes: A user can either like a content or do nothing

How can I determine which Content has got the highest popularity by using these two numbers?

I would try something like:

$s = \frac{Downloads}{Likes}$

and the Content with the lowest Value is the most popular.

e.g.:

- $\frac{10000}{100} = 100$ not so good
- $\frac{10000}{1000} = 10$ lower value, better content

---

Another approach could be adding both numbers together so:

- $10000 + 100 = 10100$ not so good
- $10000 + 1000 = 11000$ higher value, better content

Would this work and is this "fair" in real life or should I do something different?

Comment: Can you please attempt to more explicitly define what you mean by the popularity of the content?